# Length of a string in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

Why is this script producing an error?

```
 SET serveroutput ON
  BEGIN
   v_size INTEGER(20);
   v_myName VARCHAR2(50) := 'My name is Ashish Ramtri';

   v_size := LENGTH(v_myName);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_size);

  END;
  /
```

Comment: And the name of the error is?

Comment: @OlafDietsche 'twas some syntax error. And some error was there in the declarations part as well. Anyway,it got resolved. Thanks!! :D

Comment: ah the old "some syntax error" error... bane of everyone's existence

Answer (score 4):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00202) variables need to be declared with the `declare` keyword

```
SET serveroutput ON
declare
  v_size INTEGER(20);
  v_myName VARCHAR2(50) := 'My name is Ashish Ramtri';
BEGIN
   v_size := LENGTH(v_myName);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_size);
END;
/
```